# Информация об объекте при наведении

Tags: android, unity3d, sdk, vuforia, ar

Всем привет.

Есть какие ни будь библиотеки с дополненной реальностью, может vuforia или что ни будь еще..
Или как можно такое сделать?

Идея такова: Приложение, при наведении на объект получаешь какую ни будь информацию о нем. Вроде типа этого

[image: Пример]

Comment: Тоже интересует вопрос )

Answer (score 0):

Можно Vuforia, а лучше OpenCV. Но имейте в виду, что мир внутри камеры преобразуется и там действуют свои законы и математические модели.
Загляните, например, в фолиант Zissermann-Hartley [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf), и если чтение не доставляет жестокого дискомфорта - через месяц можно попробовать что-нибудь запрограммировать. 
Без математики даже не беритесь.

Непосредственно для задачи разпознавания объектов Zissermann-Hartley конечно многовато, но ознакомиться с основами в любом случае стОит. 
А непосредственно по задаче будут полезны, например, эти [видеоуроки](https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/)